# How to get the function name from the ordinal number in a COM dll

Tags: com, dll, ordinals

I am trying to get actual function names from their ordinal numbers from a COM dll. I tried using `dumpbin.exe` but it only returns `[NONAME]` for each ordinal (except the first few).

```
    ordinal hint RVA      name

         21    0 00002439 DllCanUnloadNow
         25    1 00007F41 DllGetClassObject
        116    2 0000539C DllMain
        138    3 00008633 DllRegisterServer
        176    4 00008640 DllUnregisterServer
          1      0009152E [NONAME]
          2      00154CA7 [NONAME]
          3      00154C0B [NONAME]
          4      000140C9 [NONAME]
        ...
```

The directory containing the .dll file doesn't contain any other files (*.tlb, *.lib, *.def).

Could someone tell me how to get a list of these?
Or at least the name of a specific ordinal using registry or something?

**[EDIT: Additional info]**
I cannot find the .def file for the COM dll, so I cannot use it to get the name. I am not interested in instantiating the COM class, I only want to know what function is related to a specified ordinal.

My original problem is that I have found an exception using WinDbg, which happens in 
ChartFXClientServerCore!Ordinal5507(+0x97b7), so I would like to see the specific function to try to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the OleView tool (OLE/COM Object Viewer), which ships (among others) with the Windows SDK, http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=F26B1AA4-741A-433A-9BE5-FA919850BDBF&displaylang=en. In that tool, go to File->View TypeLib and then browse to your DLL.

**EDIT:** In response to the question about the relationship between DLL ordinals and method names exposed by the typelib: It is not too common for methods exposed via COM to be also exposed via the DEF file or via __declspec(dllimport). Typically you access COM methods via their IUnknown-derived interface, after having created the corresponding class via CoCreateInstance() or similar.

The programmer of the DLL can *also* choose to expose some of the COM methods in the DEF file, but AFAIK the only way to figure out the mapping is to look at the output of dumpbin /exports, un-decorate the returned names (with undname.exe) and visually find a correspondence in the typelib.

Comment: Thanks, I am browsing my file using the tool right now, but just can't find the relation between the ordinal number and the function name.

I can't find the .def file for the library, so I have no idea how this tool works (does it get the info from registry or something?)

Answer (score 1):

If your COM component is not marked safe for scripting, it's likely that OLEView will not have any real information (i.e. it's not ment to be called from a script, so all the info (typelib) for how to call it is compiled in via the idl).

Something like [mIDA](http://cgi.tenablesecurity.com/tenable/mida.php) can get you most of that information.  You could also search [openrce](http://www.openrce.org/search/query), for NDR RPC IDL, also on [woodmann](http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/Category:Symbol_Tools), try the symbolviewer. ([RIP fravia](http://www.woodmann.com/fravia/index.htm)).